# Send POST request when a raw in google sheet is updates

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, post, notion-api

I'm managing the users of my Notion page in Sheets. Each user has email.
I want to automate providing access to that Notion. So that each time a user (email) is added to Sheets, it is auto added to Notion.

I've found a workaround for Notion API, which works fine (tested it with Postman).

What I can't do is creating a POST request to that API. Is there a way to make it directly from sheets?

I learned there is this App Script tool, which seems to run any code I like. But I'm not an engineer and can't find any sample code to use.

Answer (score 1):

To communicate with other applications using Apps Script, you can use the [`UrlFetchApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) class. To use Apps Script with the Google Sheet where you have the list of emails, you need to create a [bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#create_a_bound_script) by opening the Google Sheet, in the top menu, go to `Extensions > Apps Script`. You can use the following sample code to make a POST request:

```
// Make a POST request with a JSON payload.
var data = {
  'name': 'Bob Smith',
  'age': 35,
  'pets': ['fido', 'fluffy']
};
var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
};
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', options);
```

Also, I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68668638/17926478) with an specific use for Notion API.

You can use the installable event-driven trigger [`On edit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#event-driven_triggers) to run the request automatically when the Google Sheet is modified.

Comment: @Tanaike you're right and thank you for the observation, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for replying and reflecting on it. I believe that your answer will be useful for OP and other users.